# eBay Fulfillment API for Get Orders

Tags: node.js, meteor, ebay-api

I have tried getOrders of Trading API but it doesn't return all orders like cancelled, shipped etc. I have tried to hit Get Orders of Fulfillment API in ebay to get all the orders.

```
HTTP.call('GET','https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order',
{
{Headers: {Authorization: Bearer<AccessToken>}
}
});
```

Output is

```
    {
  "href": "https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order?filter=creationdate:%5B2016-08-16T12:53:34.299Z..%5D&limit=50&offset=0",
  "total": 0,
  "limit": 50,
  "offset": 0,
  "orders": []
}
```

It doesn't return any orders.

Anyone knows then please tell me.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The returned output has a filter on it:

```
filter=creationdate:%5B2016-08-16T12:53:34.299Z..%5D
```

So this is likely to be your problem - you probably need to specify a date range to override this.

Comment: I did as u said but still returns an empty orders array. Any idea what I might be missing here.                                    https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order?filter=creationdate:%5B2016-11-06T15:05:43.026Z..%5D&limit=50&offset=0 . Thanks

Comment: @Kunal, If you are answering your own question, you can provide an answer and explain why it works, and ideally provide a code sample - this may be useful for someone who finds the same problem in the future. After some time you can then mark your own answer as correct :)